# $.ajax request value returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple question. Why my code here is working and value returned is right:

```
var price = {};
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.coincap.io/history/30day/BTC",
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    price = data.market_cap[0];
  }
});
alert(price);
```

But here is not working returning [Object Object]??

```
var price = {};
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC",
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    price = data.price;
  }
});
alert(price);
```

I'm a newb and I'm trying learn to get values from APIs. Thanks.

Comment: Two different endpoints, two different returned values.  I'm not sure what the exact question here is.  Not every api returns the same pattern.

Comment: Use `console.log` instead. `alert` uses `toString` which converts objects to their string representation, i.e. `[Object object]`

Comment: using console.log now I cant see a single value stored in "price" variable opening console debugger. How can i store the variable as a single number representing the price?

Comment: @Raxxor You need to post what your `console.log` looks like.

Answer (score 6):

alert turns the object to a string. An object can't be represented as a string. it returns `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

I can't test myself because of cross origin limitations. But try this code please. It appears one is returning a JSON string and the other is returning an object.

```
var price = {};
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC",
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    price = data.price;
  }
});
var JSONprice = JSON.stringify(price);
console.log(JSONprice);
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan but it's not working, console.log is returning "{}"

Comment: CORS could be the problem for you there. api.binance.com is giving me a CORS error because I'm on a different domain and cross origin requests are not enabled.

Comment: And how fix this CORS error to get right values from API? sorry but i'm a newb. Also this API is public and I think it's not an authentication problem.

Comment: Are you testing you code on the same domain as you're requesting data? For example, if you're requesting data from

https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC

You need your code to be running from 

api.binance.com

Comment: If I use my browsers (Firefox and Chrome) I can see the API json values without problems. https://imgur.com/nMKcA1A